# jQuery Validate and Form Submission

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

Ok guys. I have a hard one here. This is a custom form that posts to Salesforce. The issue is disallowing the First Name field to contain numbers. Here's the jQuery that works without validation:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
function a(a){
    var b=a||"",c={};
    if(0===b.indexOf("?")&&(b=a.substr(1)),
    !b)return c;for(var e,d=b.split("&"),
    f=0,g=d.length;f<g;f+=1)e=d[f].split("="),
    2===e.length&&e[0]&&e[1]&&(c[decodeURIComponent(e[0]).toLowerCase()]=decodeURIComponent(e[1]));return c}

jQuery(".get-in-touch__form__content > form").validate({
rules: {
    first_name: "required",
    last_name:"required",
    checkbox:"required",
    phone:{required:!0,number:!0},
    email:{required:!0,email:!0}},
    errorPlacement:function(error, element){
        if(element.attr("type") == "checkbox")
            {error.appendTo(('.checkError'));
        }
        else{error.insertAfter(element);}
    }
});

jQuery(".get-in-touch__form__content > form").submit(function(b){
b.preventDefault();
var c=jQuery("#first_name").val(),
d=jQuery("#last_name").val(),
f=(
    jQuery("#company").val(), jQuery("#phone").val()
  ),
g=jQuery("#email").val(),
h=/[0-9 -()+]+$/,
i=new RegExp(/^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$/i);if(c&&d&&f&&g)
{
    var j=a(window.location.search);
    return  
 j.utm_campaign&&jQuery("input[name=00N500000093d5K]").val(decodeURICompone
    nt(j.utm_campaign)),
        j.utm_content&&jQuery("input[name=00N500000093d5t]").val(decodeURIComponent(j.utm_content)),
        j.utm_source?jQuery("input[name=00N500000093d4l]").val(decodeURIComponent(j.utm_source)):jQuery("input[name=00N500000093d4l]").val("Organic Web"),
        j.utm_term&&jQuery("input[name=00N500000093d5U]").val(decodeURIComponent(j.utm_term)),
        h.test(f)&&10===f.length?i.test(g)?(
            jQuery.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8",
                data:jQuery(this).serialize(),success:function(a){}}),
                void jQuery("#contactDraftModal").modal("show")):void
                alert("Please enter a valid email address."):void alert("Only enter numbers and do not use spaces eg. 1234567890")
    }
    }),

    jQuery(".purchase-now").click(function(){
    jQuery("html, body").animate({scrollTop:jQuery("#pkg").offset().top-130},500)
})
jQuery(".purchase-now").click(function(){
    jQuery("html, body").animate({scrollTop:jQuery("#pbgit").offset().top-130},500)
    })
});
```

And here it is with the First Name Validation:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    function a(a){
        var b=a||"",
        c={};
        if(0===b.indexOf("?")&&(b=a.substr(1)),
        !b)return c;for(var e,d=b.split("&"),
        f=0,
        g=d.length;
        f<g;
        f+=1)e=d[f].split("="),
        2===e.length&&e[0]&&e[1]&&(c[decodeURIComponent(e[0]).toLowerCase()]=decodeURIComponent(e[1]));return c}

jQuery(".get-in-touch__form__content > form").validate({
    rules: {
        first_name: {
            required: true,
            pattern: "^[a-zA-Z_]*$"
        },
        last_name:"required",
        checkbox:"required",
        phone:{required:!0,number:!0},
        email:{required:!0,email:!0}},
        errorPlacement:function(error, element){
            if(element.attr("type") == "checkbox")
                {error.appendTo(('.checkError'));
            }
            else{error.insertAfter(element);}
        }
});

jQuery(".get-in-touch__form__content > form").submit(function(b){
    b.preventDefault();
    var c=jQuery("#first_name").val(),
    d=jQuery("#last_name").val(),
    f=(
        jQuery("#company").val(), jQuery("#phone").val()
      ),
    g=jQuery("#email").val(),
    h=/[0-9 -()+]+$/,
    i=new RegExp(/^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$/i);if(c&&d&&f&&g)
    {
        var j=a(window.location.search);
        return 
        j.utm_campaign&&jQuery("input[name=00N500000093d5K]").val(decodeURIComponent(j.utm_campaign)),
        j.utm_content&&jQuery("input[name=00N500000093d5t]").val(decodeURIComponent(j.utm_content)),
        j.utm_source?jQuery("input[name=00N500000093d4l]").val(decodeURIComponent(j.utm_source)):jQuery("input[name=00N500000093d4l]").val("Organic Web"),
        j.utm_term&&jQuery("input[name=00N500000093d5U]").val(decodeURIComponent(j.utm_term)),
        h.test(f)&&10===f.length?i.test(g)?(
            jQuery.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8",
                data:jQuery(this).serialize(),success:function(a){}}),
                void jQuery("#contactDraftModal").modal("show")):
                void alert("Please enter a valid email address."):
                void alert("Only enter numbers and do not use spaces eg. 1234567890")
    }
}),

jQuery(".purchase-now").click(function(){
    jQuery("html, body").animate({scrollTop:jQuery("#pkg").offset().top-130},500)
})
jQuery(".purchase-now").click(function(){
    jQuery("html, body").animate({scrollTop:jQuery("#pbgit").offset().top-130},500)
})
});
```

Couple notes I have about the code:
Ultimately the form data is captured by `function(b)` and then submitted to `function a(a)` where it is then posted by AJAX to the Salesforce script. At least I think that's what's happening! I didn't write this code initially.

In the second set of code, the form will not let you submit with numbers in the First Name field, but the form does not submit at all. Even with the fields validated.

I think the issue has to do with the jQuery Validate rules. I did not originally write this code and I have never seen jQuery validate with `first_name: "required"`. I always see it as `first_name: {required: true}`

So I think it is taking issue with using the `first_name` rules formatted the way I have it in the second code.

I am still a noob with jQuery and backend stuff like this. It took me two days just to understand what was going on with the code!

Any help would be awesome!!!

UPDATE:
I changed all the rules to not be shorthand. Now the form will submit, but even when the first name field is not valid. It will give the "Invalid Format" message under the field, but lets the form submits anyway.

```
rules: {
    first_name: {
        required: true,
        pattern: "^[a-zA-Z_]*$"
    },
    last_name: {
        required: true
    },
    checkbox:{
        required: true
    },
    phone: {
        required: true, number: true
    },
    email:{required: true, email: true},
    errorPlacement:function(error, element){
        if(element.attr("type") == "checkbox")
            {error.appendTo(('.checkError'));
        }
        else{error.insertAfter(element);}
    }
}
```

Comment: `first_name: "required"` is acceptable shorthand for `first_name: {required: true}`.

Comment: My first guess was that your pattern was somehow bad, but no, it looks fine.

Comment: Yeah I checked my pattern a bunch. I updated my answer with something I tried.

Comment: When using jQuery Validate, you do **not** need `submit` or `click` handlers for same... it's already handled internally.  If you do, your custom `submit` or `click` handlers will likely break the validation.

Comment: If I don't use `submit` then how do I post the data to Salesforce? If you could show me some example code, that would be awesome!

Comment: I feel like it really has something to do with the definition of the variable `c` in `function a(a)`

Comment: There is an option called `submitHandler` built into the plugin... this is what you'd use for handing anything after the form is valid and when it needs to submit.  There are [thousands of examples here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery-validate%5D+submithandler), and it's documented in [the SO wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info) as well as [the official documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler).

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the info! But I am not sure how I'd go about submitting all those hidden fields using `submitHandler`?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think the reason the original author didn't use jQuery validate's `submitHandler` was because the hidden fields us `utm` and they needed to decode that from the URL of the page in order to submit that info to Salesforce